# How do I distinguish between an RxJs Observable that may return an Error and one that may not in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable

There are two "types" of [RxJS](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS) `Observable`s in my application:

1. `Observable`s that only ever return data and never return an `Error`, so I can safely `.subscribe()` to the `Observable` without passing the `error` callback
2. `Observable`s that may return data or may return an `Error`, so when subscribing to the Observable I should provide both a `next` and an `error` callback

`Observable.throw()` returns an `ErrorObservable`. So a function that returns an `Observable` of type 2 returns the type `Observable<Foo> | ErrorObservable`. If I then want to `.subscribe()` to that `Observable`, TypeScript strangely expects 0 arguments, so no `next` and no `error` callback at all, which seems wrong to me. Therefore, I believe I have to denote type 2 `Observable`s as `Observable<Foo>`. But then, as someone who wants to subscribe to that `Observable`, I never know whether the `Observable` may return an `Error` or not.

So how can I distinguish these two cases properly? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

In general every Observable can send both `next` and `error` notifications. You cannot have an Observable that isn't able to send `error` notifications.

The typings don't/can't tell you anything whether an Observable emits error because it always can. So typings help you only with the `next` values.

Note that an Observable might not emit an error itself but the error might come from a chain of operators. For example if you have `Observable.from([1, 2, 3, 4])` which typically doesn't emit any error you chain it with the following:

```
const s = new Subject<number>();

const source = Observable.from([1, 2, 3, 4])
  .merge(s)
  .map((v: number) => {
    if (v === 'a') {
      throw new Error();
    }
    return v;
  })

s.next('a' as any);
```

Would you consider `source` as an Observable that may emit an error or not?

The typings don't let you use anything other than numbers. But you can eg. by mistake pass a string.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you cannot do this using code. You may know for sure that one certain observable may never throw (for example: `Observable.from(1)` just emits one and completes; no place for an error) and omit `onError` callbacks. For others it is recommended to provide `onError` callbacks to exit gracefully.

As you mentioned, you cannot use type `Observable<Foo> | ErrorObservable` to subscribe to, as the `ErrorObservable`'s interface does not contain a `subscribe` method. As you see, it is what it is - an *error*. You used type intersection, which means that the resulting type contains only properties and methods which exist on **both** `Observable<Foo>` and `ErrorObservable` does not contain a method called `subscribe`, so the resulting type won't contain it either. You may want to use type union, like this, `Observable<Foo> & ErrorObservable`, so the resulting type contains methods that are present in at least one of the contained types, so you can then `subscribe` to it. Read more about type intersections and unions [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)

Comment: If I use the union type, I cannot `.subscribe()` directly on the `Observable`, since it may also be an `ErrorObservable`, right? Ideally, I would like the `Observable` to indicate that it returns an `Error` or not, e.g. something like `Observable<Foo, Error>`. What's the "best practice" for this case?

Comment: This is not entirely true. As a matter of fact, you do not really need such a type union. When a usual observable throws an error, it does not 'convert' to an `ErrorObservable`, but rather emits an `error` notification for observers to consume. We do use `Observable.throw` to throw errors programatically inside an Observable chain, so that an `error` notification is emitted

Answer (score 0):

I don't really believe that the distinction makes sense. An observable can always potentially emit an error, by design.

Note that if an exception is thrown anywhere in the observable code that will also result in an error being emitted, so even if you believe the observable can't emit an error there is always the faint chance of running out of memory or stack space or encountering a bug in your code, which would emit an error.

So IMO you should treat observable errors in the same way you treat exceptions in JavaScript – they need to be handled no matter where they occur. (Java, by the way distinguishes between RuntimeExceptions, which are essentially unplanned exceptions and exceptions that need be declared and caught, which is the distinction you are looking for, but JavaScript doesn't do anything like that.)

So in short: I would just add an error handler onto every observable.

Comment: An `Observable` like `Observable.from(1)` should never return an `Error`, though. To me, it doesn't make sense to add an `error` callback there ... Also, in my Angular application, there's a global error handler that catches all unhandled `Error`s. So if I forget to pass an `error` callback, the global handler will pick it up. So I'm not concerned about missing an `Error`, but it is really just about the distinction in code.